# regex: Lookaround Before/After the Match

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

consider this text: `100 dollars`

If I want to match `100` (using lookahead), I wrote this:

```
\d{3}(?= dollars)
```

and as far as I know, that pattern means: **find 3 digits only when(if) it is followed by** `" dollars"`

but lookahead can be used in an odd way; again matching `100` in the above mentioned text:

```
(?=\d{3} dollars).{3}
```

How is it possible? How do we interpret this second use of lookahead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remeber that lookarounds are zero-width assertions. Meaning that they don't consume characters as they are matching. They are basically a check from a given point in the string. In the second regex the engine first checks whether from a specific point in the string the pattern inside the lookaround matches and if so, the matching continues from that location this time by consuming characters (`.{3}`).

Comment: Beat me too it. That's a crucial thing to remember, and not necessarily the most obvious concept to grasp. Other common zero-width assertions are anchors (`^` and `$`) and word boundaries (`\b`).

Comment: @Sam This is the first time I beat you to it. You basically beat me to most regex questions I want to answer :)

Comment: so in that second pattern lookahead practically means "if" and not ahead of something?

Comment: @wiki In both scenarios you can think of it as an "if". In the first case, you first consume some characters and after they are matched you also make sure that they are followed by " dollar". In the second case you make sure that the 3 numbers are followed by dollar anywhere in the string first and after you make sure that such pattern exists, you consume 3 characters from that point in string(`.{3}`)

Comment: if lookarounds don't consume anything then if I'm not mistaken, I can create multiple IF's for checking validity of the text; something like: `(?=condition1)(?=condition2)...` right?

Comment: @wiki Correct. So for example, `ac` matches `(?=a(v|c))(?=a(c|b)).` but `av` doesn't.